# heatmap.2() overwrite colnames

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using the function heatmap.2 in R. I created an heatmap with the following conditions:

```
heatmap.2(tada1, Rowv=FALSE, Colv="FALSE", dendrogram='none', scale="row",trace='none',col=redgreen(3))
```

My problem is that the column of the heatmap contains 596 names. I cant see this names because they are overwriting each other. My Question is therefore: How can i display all the names without overwriting each other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to say "Use `cex.axis` to make the font size smaller", but I see that there is already provision in the code to make the row and column labels smaller in proportion to their numbers. See the argument list on the help page:

```
       cexRow = 0.2 + 1/log10(nr),
       cexCol = 0.2 + 1/log10(nc),
```

... so maybe you just need to purchase a magnifying glass. Or: print to a vector graphics device that is larger and scale it down. (Or provide an example so we can see what difficulty you are experiencing.

To implement my second to last suggestion you could look at this output with a pdfviewer. That should let you zoom in or out.

```
pdf(file="Hmap2.pdf", height=20, width=15)   
# will go to the working directory unless you use path
heatmap.2(tada1, Rowv=FALSE, Colv="FALSE", dendrogram='none', scale="row", 
            trace='none', col=redgreen(3)) 
dev.off()
```

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest the OP gets a bigger screen or an A1 plotter.  But magnifying glasses are an excellent suggestion!